# WPF Custom TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Hi im making a custom Textbox i got everty thing working but how do i change the color of the I that blinks when a textbox has focus?
ps the the text is inside a ScrollViewer with the property x:Name="PART_ContentHost"

Ps this is my first wpf application so im not so good yet...

[Image](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xla6py&s=5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2007/02/08/changing-caret-color-in-textbox.aspx) for a possible answer. Changing the Caret cursor is not easily supported by the WPF